# Automatic insertion of current date and time in alphabetic form

Tags: windows-7, time

I often find myself typing the current date and time on several documents, forms, etc.

Is there any lightweight application that would allow me to automatically insert (or copy to the clipboard) the current date and time (in alphabetical form, if possible) using just a simple keyboard shortcut? I'm interested in solutions for Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

An example from the [AutoHotkey documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm):

```
:*:]d::  ; This hotstring replaces "]d" with the current date and time via the commands below.
FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,, M/d/yyyy h:mm tt  ; It will look like 9/1/2005 3:53 PM
SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
return
```

An example from the AutoHotkey forum: [Input system date and/or time, when u press a hot key](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic47639.html):

```
$F12::
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
IfWinActive, Notepad
{
FormatTime, xx,, ddMMMyy ; This is one type of the date format
FormatTime, zz,, hh:mm:ss tt ; This is one type of the time format
SendInput, %xx%{Enter}
SendInput, %zz%
}
Return
```

See [FormatTime](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FormatTime.htm) for a list of the available date formats.

To set it up:

1. Download and install [AutoHotkey_L](http://www.autohotkey.com/), let it associate with .ahk files
2. Copy either of the above examples, paste in into Notepad, and save somewhere with an `.ahk` extension, e.g. My Documents/keys.ahk
3. Navigate to the file you saved and double click it
4. Add the .ahk script to your Startup folder

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very familiar with AutoHotkey, but I'll look into it. From the top of your head, is there any easy way to change the code above to print the _month_ in _alphabetical_ form ? e.g. February 2nd, 7:04pm

Comment: `MMM` for short month or `MMMM` for full month.  See http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FormatTime.htm

Answer (score 1):

Short of just copying and pasting it to your documents, there is a feature to do that on Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 0):

Phraseexpress will do it and a lot more.
https://www.phraseexpress.com/

They have a free version which is What I  use.

Make a phrase with
{#date} {#datetime -f tt}

I use ctrl alt t for a hotkey.

Pastes it anywhere on computer.